# How to obtain index in nested ng-repeats

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat within a ng-repeat. I am tyring to obtain the index at both levels but am not able to :

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="element in body">
      <td ng-repeat="h in header" style="width:{{h.width}}px">
        <div col="{{$parent.$parent.$index}}" row="{{$parent.$index}}">{{element[h.column]}}</div>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

here is a plnkr too.
http://plnkr.co/edit/dGoN43HzQefVpCsp2R3j

The ISSUE is that value of "col" never gets populated. It does not capture the index.
Can anyone assist

Comment: do you want to set outer loop index to col and inner loop index to row?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not have to use `$parent`, just use `$index` to get **index of inner loop** and use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function of array to get **index of outer loop**...

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="element in body">
  <td ng-repeat="h in header" style="width:{{h.width}}px">
    <div col="{{body.indexOf(element)}}" row="{{$index}}">{{element[h.column]}}</div>
  <td>
</tr>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Actually using [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) would much better to get **index of outer loop**... here you can easily set `rowIndex` to **current index** at every turn and use it in inner loop...

```
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="element in body" ng-init="rowIndex = $index">
      <td ng-repeat="h in header" style="width:{{h.width}}px">
        <div col="{{$index}}" row="{{rowIndex}}">{{element[h.column]}}</div>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

here is updated [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/NqgsNLl9bsLNDVKwdoFA?p=preview)

Comment: Could you please suggest, how I can achieve the same if I am getting the outer loop list from a function call like <tr ng-repeat="element in getBodyElements()">

Comment: @SoftEngi it should be same. Why do you think it should be different then this or what is your problem exactly?